# Regex with min 8 digits, 20 characters

Tags: angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

I'm currently looking for a regex that verify's the following requirements:

- Should contain atleast 8 digits (0-9).
- Between the digits it is allowed to use other characters (a-z) (also upper case).
- It should contain max 20 characters (a-z 0-9).

**example**:

```
12345678: true
123adafa45678: true
123ab456: false (needs atleast 8 digits, now only 6)
ab12345a678: true 
ab123456789afgb2459a2: false (more then 20 characters)
```

I tried serveral things but if I use something like:
`(\D*\d\D*){8,}` then it works but it doesn't meet the last requirement (up to 20 characters).

Comment: Is python good for you?

Comment: which programming language do you use?

Comment: Sorry, AngularJS but if I know how to write the regex it'll be allright I guess.

Comment: Why use a regex for this?

Comment: Other suggestions?

Comment: `/^(?=[a-z\d]{8,20}$)(?:[a-z]*\d){8}[a-z\d]*$/i`

Comment: Thank you! :) Seems to work.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to write a password strength checker? Perhaps looking for existing third party libraries or standard password checking solutions would be better? The question is framed with very precise requirements, but you would be better off thinking at the wider level because precise requirements like this can easily end up changing later, but the overall need for a password checker will remain.

Comment: No I was trying to verify if it meets the requirements for a number we use in our country to check if a company is a registered company. Password checkers wouldn't be such a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lookahead for 8 digits:

```
^(?=(.*\d){8})[a-zA-Z\d]{8,20}$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/8UMCAYpvdt).

Comment: This is a nice one, thank you! Works like a charm! Have to make two more so hopefully I'll understand it later today. :)

Comment: Yes, just it is advisable to replace `(.*\d){8}` with `(?:\D*\d){8}`.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor! Changed that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your suggestion fails if there are multiple targets separated by newlines, because `\D` matches newlines but dot does not. See your version incorrectly matching [here](http://rubular.com/r/7bmdOzWgH9).

Comment: @Bohemian: The string that is passed to this regex cannot be a multiline string. It is a *password* validation. It does not matter whether you use `\D` or `.`. I suggested `(?:[a-z]*\d){8}` in my comment anyway.

Comment: @wiktor then the millionth of a second you'll save in "performance" using `\D` on such a tiny input isn't worth bothering about